# Select 4 random rows from the first 20 rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, activemodel

In my rails code I have:

```
@vip_cars = Car.where(is_vip: true).order_by(created_at: :desc).limit(20)
```

In this code I select some data and take the first 20 rows, but from those I want to select 4 rows, selected randomly. For example `4, 9, 1, 18` ?

How to select from Model some data randomly ?

How can I do this in a ruby way?

Comment: Why limit to 20, then select 4? Why not just order randomly and take the first 4?

Comment: @Coenwulf becouse, what do you mean, show code

Comment: @Coenwulf I guess it's important that the 4 records are taken from 20 most recent.

Comment: Code might be similar to `Car.where(is_vip: true).order_by("RANDOM()").first(4)` (use RAND() instead of RANDOM() if using MySQL). The difference would obviously be that you're selecting from the whole population, not just the last 20 created.

Comment: @Coenwulf i need to select from recent 20...

Comment: @Magnuss Makes sense. I just wanted to understand why...

Answer (score 4):

I believe `sample` will help you, assuming you want 4 random ones.

```rb
@vip_cars = Car.where(is_vip: true).order_by(created_at: :desc).limit(20).sample(4)
```